# Object.prototype function to test if it is defined / not null?

Tags: javascript

I'm simply trying to avoid this

```
if(typeof myObject !== 'undefined' && myObject !== null)
{
   //safely use myObject  
}
```

so I tried this

```
Object.prototype.doesExist = function() {
    return (typeof this !== "undefined" && this !== null);
}
```

followed by

```
if(myObject.doesExist()){
   //safely use myObject
}
```

but of course the result is **myObject is not defined**

it understand why this doesn't work, but has anybody figured out a better way to accomplish what I'm looking for?

Comment: If a variable has a value of `undefined` or `null` then it's not an `Object( )` so it won't have any Object methods.

Comment: Why do you need to prototype it?  Why not create a global function?  `if( IsDefined(variable)){...}`

Comment: @AlfredoDelgado, I understand this.. I'm looking for a better way

Comment: @vol7ron only because `myObject.doesExist()` is easier to read than `doesExist(myObject)` IMO

Comment: Why not just `if (myObject) {...}`? Objects are truthy.

Comment: @Mathletics - That would evaluate as false for values of 0, empty string, etc.

Comment: @StevenMoseley I'm assuming OP is dealing with objects based on the question

Comment: @Mathletics for this instance that is true. Thanks for the solution

Comment: What @Mathletics says is true but if that's the case then he wouldn't need to do `myObject !== null` in the first place

Comment: @Mathletics - Good point.

Comment: @godmode - I added another solution to my answer, which is to use `instanceof` - I think this will be closest to what you're actually looking to do in your code.

Comment: @torazaburo I think it would be better to mark that question as a duplicate of this one, as the answers here are more extensive.

Comment: If someone else can reopen it I could do that.

Comment: @torazaburo Your javascript gold tag badge lets you reopen it instantly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the comments, `null` or `undefined` are not instances of an `Object`, so they won't inherit Object's prototype.

**Solution 1:** Use a static Object method, which is a functional, though not quite as clean, solution similar to what you were trying to do.

```
Object.exists = function(obj) {
    return typeof obj !== "undefined" && obj !== null;
}

if (Object.exists(myObject)) {
   // safely use myObject
}
```

**Solution 2:** Use `instanceof` if you know what type of object you're expecting.  This is recommended if you will be accessing ClassName's interface inside your if statement.

```
if (myObject instanceof ClassName) {
    // safely use myObject
}
```

Examples:

```
function A() {}
var a = new A(), b;

> a instanceof A
true
> a instanceof Object
true

> b instanceof A
false
> b instanceof Object
false

> null instanceof A
false
> null instanceof Object
false

> undefined instanceof A
false
> undefined instanceof Object
false
```

I think that handles your use-cases

Comment: Why not just `if (myObject) { }`?

Comment: @Mathletics - That would evaluate as `false` for values of 0, empty string, etc.

Comment: this will throw an error : ReferenceError: myObject is not defined

Comment: @Anonymous0day only if that variable is not declared.

Comment: @Mathletics, not **not initialized**, but indeed - _not defined_

Comment: @Grundy oops, I meant the other one.

Comment: @Mathletics you're right ! sorry for the disturbing :-), let's continue !

Comment: `instanceof` is notoriously unreliable!

Comment: @Mathletics - Cite your source or prove your claim.  I've used it without any issues for quite some time.

Comment: @StevenMoseley [`instanceof` lies](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/common-misconceptions-about-inheritance-in-javascript-d5d9bab29b0a#b7d3)

Comment: @Mathletics - So basically, it works in every use case you would ever experience in a sanely designed product, and is still infinitely better than `if (myObject)`.  So what's your objection?

Comment: @StevenMoseley LOL "sanely designed product." When you find one of those, send me a link! :-p

Comment: @Mathletics - jQuery uses `instanceof`.  I guess it qualifies as sanely designed :)

Answer (score 2):

Loose equality will achieve the desired result without monkey-patching although it requires some knowledge of javascript's semantics:

```
myObject == null; //true for null and undefined, false for all others
```

You can also use logical and as a guard operator:

```
if ((myObject != null) && myObject.someMethod && myObject.someMethod());
```

Obviously you could criticize the above for readability, but because javascript dumps everything into the same global namespace I'd be very careful about adding even static methods to `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

I know you may not like having a global function, but I believe that's the only solution.

```
function isObject (v) {
    return (typeof v === 'object' && v != null);
    // (Technically null is an object, but is often considered a non-object)
}

if (isObject(myObject)) {
    //safely use myObject
}
```